# MS Access ER diagram

Tags: schema, ms-access

I have database scheme for Microsoft Access. I'm interested how I can convert the scheme into an ER diagram? Is there any tool that can do this based on scheme relations?

Answer (score 2):

Visio Professional(prior to 2013) has an option to [reverse engineer a database schema](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-HA010115485.aspx).  I have used this in the past for Access as well as other databases.  However, it does mean you have to purchase the professional version.

You could also migrate the database schema into SQL Server and leverage the [database diagrams](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/) found there.  You should be able to use [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Export a database schema from MS Access seems impossible. The only way is to migrate your database to [MySQL Worbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) which has a real modeling and migration tool. With the option of reverse engineering, you'll be able to get a ER Diagram of your database. In this DBMS, you can also specify the type of normalization (e.g UML) that you want.

The other option is to create your own ER Diagram without an importation via some free software like [UMLnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/umlnet/) (but can appear very long depending of database size).